# kk Star Ratings average

Tags: wordpress, plugins, average

I use the  "kk Star Ratings" plugin in WordPress.
(https://wordpress.org/plugins/kk-star-ratings/).
But I want to output the number of average and total ratings of each post by variables.
What code should I use?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You try to configure [WP-PostRatings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/) plugin in wordpress.

Thanks..

Comment: But I have to use kk Star Ratings !

Comment: yes, I know but you can use this. so you can easy to use in your site. Otherwise you have to customize the plugin if it's possible in kk plugin